# calculate duration with overlapping years

Tags: r

I have a large job-exposure database, and I wanted to calculate the duration of exposure of each subject to each agent. But a subject can be exposed to an agent through different jobs. For each job, I have the start year and end year. There are overlapping periods between the jobs, and I want to find the total duration of exposure to the agent with R while counting for the overlapping years only once (If I count it in job1, I don't want to recount it in job 2). For example with the subject 2, he was exposed to agent A through his job1 and job2 and we have the YEARIN and YEAROUT for each job, but there is a 3 years overlap between the 2 jobs (1998-2000).

Here is the data, called datatest:

```
structure(list(ID = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 15, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
20, 20, 20), JOB = c(1, 2, 7, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
6), AGENT = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", 
"A", "A", "C", "C", "C"), YEARIN = c(1998, 1996, 1979, 1978, 
1973, 1973, 1979, 1976, 1980, 1970, 1978, 1984, 1988, 1996, 2000
), YEAROUT = c(2009, 2000, 1985, 1982, 2006, 2006, 2007, 1985, 
2008, 2005, 1979, 1995, 1993, 2002, 2008)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

So I was suggested to use this code to find the durations and it works well :

```
datatest %>%    group_by(ID, JOB, AGENT) %>%    summarise(year = seq(YEARIN, YEAROUT, by=1)) %>%    unnest(year) %>%    group_by(ID, AGENT) %>%    summarise(nyear = length(unique(year)))
```

Now I'm having another issue. I've group my agents in categories and I want to calculate the duration for each category.

I want to group agent A and B in a category called M, and agents C and D in a category called N. I created an another variable called AGENT_group with ifelse. And the data look like this now :

```
structure(list(ID = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 15, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
20, 20, 20), JOB = c(1, 2, 7, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
6), AGENT = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", 
"A", "A", "C", "C", "C"), YEARIN = c(1998, 1996, 1979, 1978, 
1973, 1973, 1979, 1976, 1980, 1970, 1978, 1984, 1988, 1996, 2000
), YEAROUT = c(2009, 2000, 1985, 1982, 2006, 2006, 2007, 1985, 
2008, 2005, 1979, 1995, 1993, 2002, 2008), AGENT_GROUP = c("M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "N", "N", "N", "M", "M", "N", "N", 
"N")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

But When I used the same code as the one I was suggested before I have this error :

`` Error in `summarise()`: ! Problem while computing `year = seq(YEARIN, YEAROUT, by = 1)`. ℹ The error occurred in group 5: ID = 7, JOB = 1, AGENT_GROUP = "M". Caused by error in `seq.default()`: ! 'from' must be of length 1 Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. ``

I believe it is because we have AGENT_GROUP M twice for the same YEAR IN YEAR OUT, same ID and same job. I'm trying to figure out how to get around this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
datatest %>%    
  group_by(ID, JOB, AGENT, AGENT_GROUP) %>%
  summarise(year = seq(YEARIN, YEAROUT, by=1)) %>%    
  unnest(year) %>%    group_by(ID, AGENT, AGENT_GROUP) %>%    
  summarise(nyear = length(unique(year)))  %>%  
  group_by(ID, AGENT_GROUP) %>% summarize(nyear = sum(nyear))
```

Probem is that you're grouping by agent_group but not by agent. You do the grouping by both columns first then finally group and sum by agent_group.

**NOTE that this return the sum of years** if you want the unique simultaneous years by group in the same fashion that you did by AGENT, you do:

```
datatest %>%    
  group_by(ID, JOB, AGENT, AGENT_GROUP) %>%
  summarise(year = seq(YEARIN, YEAROUT, by=1)) %>%    
  unnest(year) %>%    group_by(ID, AGENT_GROUP) %>%    
  summarise(nyear = length(unique(year)))
```

Comment: I realized that when I run the code I have this error message warning message:
" Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
ℹ Please use `reframe()` instead.
ℹ When switching from `summarise()` to `reframe()`, remember that `reframe()` always returns an ungrouped data frame and adjust accordingly.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated. " Does it mean that using summarise is not ok and I should use reframe instead. Or I can still use summarise ?

Comment: Yes, to avoid amibguity, newer versions explicitly require "reframe" to return more than a row per group (like this example, in which the result is a sequence of dates). So use "reframe". Other solution can be using a mutate with a nested list then unnest: `mutate(year = list(seq(YEARIN, YEAROUT, by=1))) %>% unnest(year)`